# Replicate a Postman POST-Request (metadata and fileupload) within python

Tags: python, post, request, postman

I am trying to issue a POST request including local-file upload with python.

I looked up a lot of similar requests here, but none worked for me or none was specific enough to help me out.

With Postman everything works as expected and without any hickups.
But representing the very same with python I am not able to achieve it. 
I tried various combinations of params-, body- and file-dictionaries, without success

This is how the working postman request body looks like:
[image: Postman: RequestBody]

This is how the params of this postman request have been configured:
[image: Postman Params]
This is my python code

```
metadata = {
    "name":"MyFile" , 
    "type":"myFileType" ,
    "parentId":"1cc58622-3bc0-4fc4-a222-a64bd8d90af1"
    }

fileForUpload = {'upload_file': open("/home/myuser/blablabla/testfile.jpg)", "rb")}

params = {"metadata":json.dumps(metadata), "file": "filename"}
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json", 
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token,
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
    }
response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, params = params, files = fileForUpload)
```

I receive an error message of the API-endpoint, claiming that the file parameter is missing ...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try this: params = {"metadata":json.dumps(metadata), "file": open("/home/myuser/blablabla/testfile.jpg)", "rb")} . You might have to convert your file into a bytestream though

Comment: @MartinNowosad putting the "opened" file into the params-dictionary didn't work. Still the error message is "missing file parameter". When I remove the "metadata" key from the dictionary, the error message changes to "missing metadata parameter". 
How can I change the file to a bytestream? Maybe this is really the key to success here?

Comment: Postman shows following parameters in its console:
**metadata = { "name": "MyFile", "type":...." } file = [object Object]**

So the file seems really to be an object or a stream. How to achieve this in python?